# Node js error on live server after update node version

Tags: node.js, cakephp

I am using node js for live streaming in my project
it's working fine but now some change in my server and i need to install again node on my server
previously its working but now it gives me following error

```
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/home/deemtech/public_html/dev/chem/app/webroot/js/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:73:13)
    at Socket.onend (_stream_readable.js:483:10)
    at Socket.g (events.js:175:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

node version : v0.10.18

How could i solve this error

thanks in advance

Comment: It appears that your connection to the MySQL server was lost. Hard to guess without seeing code and configuration, but I am *guessing* that you changed other things, possibly the connection string you are using to connect to MySQL (either in a configuration file, or possibly in an environment variable). One possible such change is the "connection timeout", which will make MySQL close idle connections.

Comment: which code do you want to see ?

Comment: this is a code for connection

var mysql   = require('mysql');

var sqlDump,client_index, connectionsArray = [];
var dbConn = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'deemtech_admin',
    password    : 'Deem123',
    database    : 'deemtech_chem'
});
dbConn.connect(function(err) { console.log(err); });

Comment: Well my guess may have been wrong. Just to make sure: have you changed anything on the server? mysqld options? Environment vars? Also, it appears that you are not waiting for the `coonect` to return before proceeding with your code, this might explain things.

Comment: yes some change in server
so administrator install again node on server
so changed node version from this